# how can transform the new codument for classification acoording to TFIDF trained dataset

Tags: python-3.x

i have corpus of three  categorized text files :
1- i calculate tfidf for the vectors of each category 
2- splited the dataset for 2 parts training and testing set
3- trained the tfidf data using NaiveBayesClassifier.train

then i want to classify new document , it should be transformed for the tame form of the trained data >>> so i should to vectorize it to its' TFIDF 
1-i tokenized it 
2-calculate the TF term (the number of the word occurrence in the new document divided by the number of words in the whole new document)
3-the idf term (log (number of all documents(in this case one because it just one file that i want to classify) divided by the number of documents that contain the word(in this case one because it just one file that i want to classify))
4- so the idf term for all vectors in the new file is zerooo ----- i ultered the formula to IDF= l+(log(N/Ni)) to avoid the zero values 
5 = calculate the tfidf values for each vector in the new document by TF*IDF 
5-then classify the new document using NaiveBayesClassifier.classify

but the classification values not true ,,, please anybody help me

Comment: sorry I'm a new user , and just wanted to describe my problem briefly